# Weird characters appearing after domain name in address bar

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on this WordPress site: http://greenarea.me/en/
And something weird started happening after a while, if you access the site, this code will appear next to the domain name #.Vp37JlN96DU, so it becomes: http://greenarea.me/en/#.Vp37JlN96DU

Is is because of a plugin? I don't know the reason it appears.
Any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: It could be caused by a plugin. Try deactivating your plugins one by one and check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is caused by addthis plugin (by addthis_widget.js to be precise).